# Redirect with a dash / hyphen

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to do a redirect of http://www.example.com/2-for-1 to http://www.example/article/1.
Either everything I've tried so far is incorrect or the server is screwed up.

Can someone knowledgeable kindly tell me the correct syntax so I may verify if the server settings are incorrect?

These are some of my more recent attempts:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)2(\-)for(\-)1$ http://www.example.com/article/1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/2\-for\-1$ /article/1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule    ^2-for-1/?$    article/1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Your last example works for me. Check that you don't have a rule before it that stops it happening, and that you have `RewriteEngine on` in your .htaccess.

Comment: Also, do you want to see the rewritten URL in the browser? If so you need to add the `[R]` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[^-]+-for-([^/]+)/?$ /article/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```